# How to fix node in armv5

Tags: path, arm, node.js, npm

I am trying to fix nodejs on mlinux. So when i do a `uname -m` the output is `armv5tejl`. It came with pre-installed node and npm. I tried to upgrade but somehow i think I have broken something.

Now when i do a `node -v` i get

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/node: No such file or directory
```

When i do a `npm -v` i get

```
1.4.23
```

`echo $PATH` gives me

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Output of `which node`

```
/usr/local/bin/node
```

Output of `which npm`

```
/usr/bin/npm
```

Since /usr/local/bin is in the PATH i am having difficulties fixing this issue. How can i fix this ? Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: Do you remember what you did when trying to upgrade?

Comment: i tried to upgrade node using node-v0.10.40-linux-arm-v7.tar.gz library which i think was the wrong one for the linux arch i have. I extracted the package and copied the contents to /usr/local